# taking photo from web app on android 2.3

Tags: android, android-camera, android-browser

I´m aware of the existence of Device API and its availability on Android 3.0+ to accomplish this, but, is there an alternative to achieve the same for Android 2.3+?

Something similar to PhoneGap, but not creating a client app. Something purely web.

The user story is simple: from web browser, user takes a picture and uploads it to server.

I appreciate any ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the whole tutorial, but this looks like it could help you.

[Jquery webcam photobooth](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/04/jquery-webcam-photobooth/)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out this tutorial, its very good. However I´m not sure it would work for Android 2.3, given that the tutorial assumes you are using a PC. I will give it a try and mark as answer if it works from Android 2.3.